# Any way to install python 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, python

I have some project that needs python 3.4 but since I am on Ubuntu 18.04 I have python 3.6 installed. If I try to setup the project on 3.6 I get compatibility issues. Please guide how do I install python 3.4 alongside 3.6. And is there a way to make virtualenv use python 3.4 to setup environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By compile the binary:

Download the zip package of python3.4 from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/Python-3.4.4.tgz)

extract it and enter in the folder

1. execute: `./configure`
2. execute: `make -j 4` If you have more core insert the number of core of your cpu
3. execute: `make test -j 4` same as above, *OPTIONAL but suggested!*
4. execute: `sudo make install`

**If you find the binary package you can skip the compilation steps.**

Install virtualenv:

```
sudo apt install virtualenv
```

then create a virtual environment with desired python version:

1. `virtualenv --python=python3.4 --clear --always-copy --setuptools .venv`
2. `virtualenv .venv --distribute`

*note: `.venv` is the path where virtual environment is installed*

Alternative to a virtual environment you can use the python executable directly from path you choose, but I recommend you to use a virtual environment, keep your system more clean.

to activate the virtual environment execute the bash script perform following steps:

1. `source .venv/bin/activate`

to exit from the virtualenv

2. `exit` will close the terminal and the virtualenv.

You can also configure mostly of IDE to use the python virtual env.